# How can I add a column that sorts the last "n" values?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with columns `Active`  and `Cycles`.
I want to add a third column called `state` which is classified according to the number of cycles.

For example: for the first 20 that the state of Normal goes, for the last 20 "emergency "and for the rest" normal "

I have tried creating data frame for the last and first values and then joining them but it is cumbersome and I can't figure out how to place the label on the middle data.

```
df  <-  data_frame %>% 
         group_by(ACT) %>%
           top_n(20)
df=mutate(df, Fault = "EMERGENCIA")
```

It occurred to me that with `ifelse` it would be easier but I don't know what to put in the last condition.

```
Dt <- data_frame %>%
  group_by(ACT) %>%
  mutate(Faul = ifelse(CYCLE <= 20 , "Normal", 
                        ifelse(20 < CYCLE & CYCLE < ???????, "alerta", "emergencia")))
```

Comment: Please add some sample data!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `case_when` to distinguish the cases:

```
data_frame %>%
  mutate(Faul = case_when(CYCLE <= 20 ~ "Normal",
                          CYCLE <= 40 ~ "alerta",
                          TRUE ~ "emergencia"))
```